# Can't buy off of Software Centre

Tags: software-installation

For an odd reason, when I try to purchase something on the Software Centre, it processes the request, and never stops processing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting Ubuntu. Check for updates using

sudo apt-get update

Followed by

sudo apt-get upgrade

This might fix some store errors.

Comment: I haven't used this operating system before, or Linux for that matter, would you mind giving me some directions on how to preform the restart. Is it just a restart of the computer?